# How can I run executable .sh file with input prompts all 'yes' from outside current directory?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a **.sh** file in folder like `/home/folder1 /folder2 /xyz.sh`

I want to run **.sh** from folder1 but assume that the answer to any question  which  would be asked will be '**yes**'

Then what more should I use with this command => `home/folder1$ ./folder2/xyz.sh`

Answer (score 2):

To answer `yes` on every input, use the `yes` command:

```
yes yes | /home/folder1/folder2/xyz.sh
```

Comment: Twice 'yes' ? @John1024

Comment: @DebanjanaSarkar `yes` once will emit the string `y` repeatedly.  `y` is the default output for `yes`.    You, however, asked for the string `yes`. `yes yes` will repeatedly emit the string `yes`.

Comment: It's showing 
/bin/sh: yes yes | /home/folder1/folder2/xyz.sh: No such file or directory 

INFO[0531] The command [/bin/sh -c "yes yes | /home/folder1/folder2/xyz.sh"] returned a non-zero code: 127

Comment: @DebanjanaSarkar That is an odd message.  It looks like there's something quoted wrong.  Also, why are you using `/bin/sh -c "..."`?  What is the result of `ls -l /home/folder1/folder2/xyz.sh` ? What is the result of `command -v yes`?  How are you actually invoking the command?

Comment: ls -l showing -rwxrwxr-x. 1 polaris polaris 2847 Aug 10 01:39 /home/folder1/folder2/xyz.sh & command -v yes showing /usr/bin/yes

Comment: That is a very good start.  And, the answers to my other two questions?

Answer (score 0):

Which commands are you using inside of the shell script? Most commands have a batch mode. Often it is `-f` for force (as in `rm` and `cp`).